# write a string contain html tag on the page to create a html table in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc

I use this code to return an string from my action :

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        string List = "";       
        List = "<table><tr><td>Ali</td></tr></table>";
        ViewData["List"] = List;
        return View();

    }
```

and this is  my view :

```
<body>
<%: ViewData["List"] %>
</body>
```

but instead to create a table when i browse the page , i see that the string `"<table><tr><td>Ali</td></tr></table>"` wrote on it. I use the firebug and see its html code . but i saw something like this :

```
&lt;table&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;Ali&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;/table&gt;
```

Is there any body out there to help me?

Thansk
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you use the HtmlEncode tag

Change the `<%:` to `<%=`

will be come

```
<body>
<%= ViewData["List"] %>
</body>
```

and do not forget to HtmlEncode your data only to avoid any injection.

Comment: thanks, forcefully by SO I`ll accept you answer in 15 minutes ago